# How to customize Date and Time field in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How to customzie the default dateTime field in django forms to be more friendly to the user.

forms.py:

```
class new_album_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = album
        fields = ['album_name', 'album_artist', 'released_at', 'price', 'is_approved']
```

and I am using the default django forms

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{form.as_p}}
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

[My field output in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArUeQ.png)

[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoMuf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ------ form.py ---------

```
class new_album_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = album
        fields = ['album_name', 'album_artist', 'released_at', 'price', 'is_approved']

         widgets = {
            'released_at':forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local'}),
        }
```

### ------ Output --------

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected out, I think you have to add widgets to your form.

try this:

```
class new_album_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = album
        fields = ['album_name', 'album_artist', 'released_at', 'price', 'is_approved']
        widgets = {
               'album_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form- 
                control'}),
               'album_artist': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form- 
                control'}),
               'release_at': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form- 
                control', 'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'}),
               #Add your remaining widgets here
        }
```

And in templates:

```
<input type="date" data-target="#datetimepicker1" class="form-control" value="{{form.release_at}}" />  #form is a context name from views.py file
```

Comment: The default widget for `DateTimeField` is `DateTimeInput` not `DateInput` that's for `DateField`.

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot that will update now

Comment: I am using the default django forms